# Return records from 2 tables using mysql and rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

need help with this please:
 `@follows = Follow.where("admin_user_id = ?", session[:id])`

This returns records from the Follow table, that has the following coloumns, :admin_user_id, :assignment_id. I would now like to do this:

```
@assignments = Assignment.where("id = ?", @follows.assignment_id)
```

The Asssignment table has the following columns, :id, :name.I have tried the "@follows.assignment_id" to substitute each id which i can then use in the view like,

```
<% @assignment.each do |assignment| %>
     <%= assignment.name %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This is the error i get:undefined method `assignment_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6d8104c>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem here is your first query: `Follow.where(...)` returns a scope, it will not perform the query until you try to access the `@follows` object. This is probably not a big deal, but you should probably make it this (unless you are going to dynamically add more conditions):

```
@follows = Follow.where("admin_user_id = ?", session[:id]).all
```

This ensures that @follows is an array of Follow objects.  Because it's an array (and not a single `Follow`) there is no assignment_id on it.  Change your second query to this:

```
@assignments = Assignment.where(:id => @follows.map{|f| f.assignment_id}).all
```

Basically, `.map` returns an array of the return values of the block instead of the original object it was called on, meaning instead of an array of follows, it returns an array of the assignment ids of each object.  When you pass this array as the conditions, it generates a SQL query something like:

```
select * from assignments where id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

if your follows have assignment ids 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: I should add a comment here that Kyle's answer is also correct, the only difference is in his example, each `f.assignment` call will cause another query (unless you have eagerly loaded the assignment for Follows ahead of time).  This may or may not matter to you for performance reasons.  Just two different ways of getting the same result.

Comment: Thanks Brett, it is better to get those best practices handled early!

Comment: @Kyle No problem, after a little while you just start doing it without thinking about it :)

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assignment
end
```

For Assignments

```
class Assignments < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows
end
```

Then you can call

```
@assignments = []
@follows.collect {|f| @assignments << f.assignment}
```

**Also:**

```
This is the error i get:undefined method `assignment_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6d8104c>
```

Make sure your sql table has a column called **assignment_id** with an integer value